# What does user/1234 mean in #2629286?

Tags: users

I was trying to figure out the exact problem of this issue ([Use `getDisplayName()` for user names consistently](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2629286)), what does `user/1234` mean in:

> Realname module alters the display name, but at `user/1234` the username
>   is shown. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

`user/1234` refers to the path-- the "URL" in Drupal.

In Drupal, by default, each user has his/her own URL at `user/UID`.  This `user/1234` is referring to a user account with the UID of `1234`, which is just to be an example, 1-2-3-4.

The problem described in that issue is that Drupal 8 has three functions to get a username:

`getUsername()` and `getAccountName()`: These two functions return the value of the `username` without modification.

`getDisplayName()`: This function returns the value of the `username` after letting modules modify/filter it.

The bug described in the issue explains that when you go to the user path/URL for a user, you see the unmodified, unfiltered username, but you should actually see the filtered version with `getDisplayName()`.

This issue causes serious problems for the Real Name module and any other module that tries to modify how the username is displayed; there are some patches in the issue which "mostly" fix the issue (I have used a few on different sites of mine), but there is no peer-reviewed, all-tests-passing patch yet.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The idea is that Drupal should show the display name in any post and comment created by a user, in the same way Stack Exchange sites do; the username should just be used to authenticate the users.